# three.js - how to use alphatest value inside ShaderMaterial and fragmentShader

Tags: three.js, fragment-shader

Thansks to @Mugen87, I managed to create a dynamic mask on my scene using a post processing method  : https://jsfiddle.net/40gef6sz/ (if you move the camera you will see the cube disappear behind and invisible circle, made with this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4GXm.jpg)

I would like to add some effects on my mask using a fragment shader script. On this fiddle you can see my texture moving (I replaced a `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial` with a `THREE.ShaderMaterial`) : https://jsfiddle.net/grc_michael/ghmf5sdo/

When I combine this new material with the post processing method, I can't reach the same result than the first jsfiddle. I don't know where to add my #define ALPHATEST value inside my fragment shader.
You can see the result here : https://jsfiddle.net/grc_michael/82bkLn96/

I think I'm quite close the expected result. Does anyone know where to add the ALPHATEST value properly inside my fragment shader ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here us the original, updated fiddle with your custom shader material: https://jsfiddle.net/k2c5upfo/1/

When using an image as an alpha map, you can sample it in the same way like built-in materials. Meaning the alpha test looks like so:

```
if (texture2D(texture1,xy).g < 0.5) discard;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Thank you for your time and explanations !